# Not able to use spring Beans outside container . Always picking up WebSphere Context

Tags: java, spring, websphere

We have the a whole lot of spring bean defined in our project which we deploy in Websphere ^. One example being the following:

```
<bean id="oasJdbcData" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionCacheImpl">
        <property name="driverType">
            <value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="URL">
            <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:1521:OASIS</value>
        </property>
        <property name="user">
            <value>oasis_owner</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>o3ngin33r</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Now we have a service locator class like following

```
private static ServiceLocator serviceLocator = new ServiceLocator();

private static ApplicationContext beanFactory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(APPLICATION_CONTEXT_LOCATION);

protected ServiceLocator() { 
}

public ApplicationContext getBeanFactory() {
    return beanFactory;
}

public static ServiceLocator getInstance() {
    return serviceLocator;
```

Now when I am trying to do this from my jUnit

```
ServiceLocator.getInstance().getBean("oasJdbcData";
```

getting the following exception

```
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Could not obtain an initial context due to a communication failure. Since no provider URL was specified, the default provider URL of "corbaloc:iiop:1.0@192.168.255.1:2809/NameService" was used.  Make sure that any bootstrap address information in the URL is correct and that the target name server is running.  Possible causes other than an incorrect bootstrap address or unavailable name server include the network environment and workstation network configuration. [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect:host=192.168.255.1,port=2809  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E02  completed: No]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mapInitialReferenceFailure(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1968)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1172)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:720)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:643)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:489)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:428)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:144)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:361)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:88)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:200)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
    ... 33 more
```

which clearly shows it is looking for IntialContext of Websphere
which I dont want
Any body can tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your platform (operating system and more specifically the networking settings) is screwed up. Probably you have misconfigured routing settings, firewall, or dns settings. The funny thing is, fixing those might not fix your WAS as it saves certain settings when creating profile. Please start all over and make sure the platform is healthy before you install anything.